# Software inventory

Tags: windows

Is there a script\ powerpack that can be used to Inventory the software on the PC's in certain OU's?

Answer (score 1):

[Spiceworks](http://spiceworks.com) will do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

OCS Inventory NG http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/
WInventory  http://winventory.sourceforge.net/

both free and opensource

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager

Answer (score 0):

I use LANSweeper for this: http://www.lansweeper.com/